# summing series irrespective of convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges to a $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$ converges to b $
\in \mathbb{R}$ for real sequences $\{a_{n}\}$ and $\{b_{n}\}$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n} +b_{n})$ converges to $a + b$. Do mathematicians ever write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n} +b_{n})$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ + $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$ if they don't know whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$ converge or not?
Thanks!

Comment: One has to define what is meant by addition on the RHS, as the sums are not real numbers if the series diverge.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering, it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be inadvisable to do so. If one of the two series converges (let's say it has the value $t\in\mathbb{R}$), and the other diverges, then writing
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n+b_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$
results in either $\infty=\infty+t$ or $-\infty=-\infty+t$, which are sensible and consistent definitions. However, there is really no sensible definition of $\infty-\infty$, and this can occur if both series diverge.

For example, if $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=-\frac{1}{n}$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty,\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=-\infty,\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n+b_n)=0,$$
while if $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=-\frac{1}{2n}$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty,\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=-\infty,\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n+b_n)=\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

As Sammy Black said, the right hand side does not make sense unless both series converge. As an example take $a_i = 1$ and $b_i = -1$. Then $\sum (a_i + b_i) = \sum 0 = 0$ but $\sum a_i = \infty$ and $\sum b_i = -\infty$. As we see here ([$\infty - \infty = 0$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269337/infty-infty-0/)) it's problematic to have $0 = \infty - \infty$. If the series just don't converge (even to $\infty$) then it makes even less sense. Writing these things, we're not really working with the series but with the real numbers that happen to have an infinite sum representation. So you can only compare those series (on the LHS and RHS) if they represent definite real numbers, i.e. they all converge.